# The precise proof of the properties about composite function

Tags: functions

I know the properties of composite function below.(if $g^{-1}(x)$ exists)
$$f(g(x)) = h(x) \Leftarrow\Rightarrow f(x) = h(g^{-1}(x))$$
And I tried to prove it like this.

$$X = g(x)$$
$$x = g^{-1}(X)$$
$$f(g(x)) = h(x) \rightarrow f(X) = h(g^{-1}(X))$$
But, I'm not sure it's established $f(X) = h(g^{-1}(X)) \rightarrow f(x) = h(g^{-1}(x))$

It seems to be established intuitionally, but I want to know the precise proof of it.

How can this problem be proved precisely? Or is this just universal truth?

Comment: It's better to plug things in than to pull them out.  $f(g(x)) = h(x)$ *for ALL* $x$.  So plug *in*  $g^{-1}(x)$.  It would have to be that $f(g(g^{-1}x)) = h(g^{-1}(x))$.

Answer (score 0):

$\implies$

If $f(g(x)) = h(x)$ then let $y = g^{-1}(x)$.

$f(g(y)) = h(y)$

$f(g(g^{-1}(x)) = h(g^{-1}(x))$

$f(x) = h(g^{-1}(x))$

$\Leftarrow$

If $f(x) = h(g^{-1}(x))$ then let $y = g(x)$ so

$f(y) = h(g^{-1}(y))$

$f(g(x)) = h(g^{-1}(g(x)))= h(x)$.

That's it.